# SQLDeveloper doesn't prompt for input a second time

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm used to Toad, where just by clicking F9 it would automatically prompt me to type my input parameters for any query.

However, in SQLDeveloper I am only prompted to input them once, & then every time I use F9 the tool uses the inital parameters, forcing me to close & reopen a script if I want to change the parameter.

Do you know of any command to prevent this?

Comment: What version of SQL Developer are you using?  What does your query look like?  If I run the query `select 1 from dual where 1 = :foo;` by hitting F9 in SQL Developer 19.4.0.354, I always get the Enter Binds dialog.  Are you saying that the dialog doesn't open for you?

Comment: & vs && - try it

Comment: I'm using & and &&. It just prompts me once. Then, running again it acts as if I had already provided those.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer 1.5.5

Comment: SQL Developer 1.5.5 is pretty ancient.  Have you tried downloading a current version?

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't noticed. I just requested for it (you, know, softwarr policies). I hope I get it approved or it will be a nightmare. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to resolve it permanently, but I found a work-around. Probably it's even the correct approach.

In order to reuse a variable in a query, particularly in SQL Developer, use "UNDEFINE":

```
UNDEFINE [variable_name];
```